# What is this part responsible for? The one behind the sticker in Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, gps, hardware

Below is an image. What is that part responsible for?

I'm asking because lately I had some problems with the GPS in my Galaxy S3, and I found out this sticker doesn't stick well. I think, but am not 100% sure, that when I hold it with my finger, the GPS works better.

I've been in a phone repair center, and I've been told that this is not related to the GPS, and that the GPS antenna is in the right, but they couldn't answer as of what this part is for.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While it's not clearly identified what this specific sticker is and covers, [based on this teardown](https://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Samsung+Galaxy+S+III+Teardown/9391), it does look as though the chip is on the direct other side of the board from the connector that touches the component on that sticker, suggesting the connector is directly attached through the board to that chip. So my instinct is that you're correct that it's related to the GPS. I cannot confirm this without a doubt, but everything lines up.